# Transaction Fail - wallet to wallet & wallet to contract balance

Tags: token, solidity, binance, remix, binance-smart-chain

I've just started with Solidity and, in order to understand and learn Solidity and the combination with Remix, I've copied some contracts.
At the moment I'm testing the contract "Token69", if I try do deploy the token now, I get the error message:

**"creation of Token69 errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)"**

I found out that the reason for my problem is because of the data laying in the constructor. Can I delete these parts of the code without any problems or do I have to fulfill those with data?
In addition to that, if I take out the Constructor and try to deploy the token (everything on standard gas limit and fee all other standard value of Remix) the token is permanently on "pending Token creation"
There is no error or bug report or anything. I don't really know what to do.

Can anyone help me, please?

---

I've tested another contract and now I can deploy the contract and token are sent to my wallet but I can't transfer the token to another wallet. I can't find the problem in this contract, can anybody help me with this?

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

interface IBEP20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}

library Address {

    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
        // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
        // for accounts without code, i.e. `keccak256('')`
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls, avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, errorMessage);
    }

    function _functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 weiValue, string memory errorMessage) private returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{ value: weiValue }(data);
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
            // Look for revert reason and bubble it up if present
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                // The easiest way to bubble the revert reason is using memory via assembly

                // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract TestToken is Context, IBEP20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isCharity;
    address[] private _excluded;
    address[] private _charity;
    
    string  private constant _NAME = 'TestToken';
    string  private constant _SYMBOL = 'TT';
    uint8   private constant _DECIMALS = 18;
   
    uint256 private constant _MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private constant _DECIMALFACTOR = 10 ** uint256(_DECIMALS);
    uint256 private constant _GRANULARITY = 100;
    
    uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000000000 * _DECIMALFACTOR;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (_MAX - (_MAX % _tTotal));
    
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    uint256 private _tBurnTotal;
    uint256 private _tCharityTotal;
    
    uint256 private     _TAX_FEE = 500; // 5% BACK TO HOLDERS
    uint256 private    _BURN_FEE = 500; // 5% BURNED
    uint256 private _CHARITY_FEE = 100; // 1% TO CHARITY WALLET
    uint256 private constant _MAX_TX_SIZE = 1000000000000000 * _DECIMALFACTOR;

    // Track original fees to bypass fees for charity account
    uint256 private ORIG_TAX_FEE = _TAX_FEE;
    uint256 private ORIG_BURN_FEE = _BURN_FEE;
    uint256 private ORIG_CHARITY_FEE = _CHARITY_FEE;

    constructor () {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _NAME;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _SYMBOL;
    }

    function decimals() public pure returns (uint8) {
        return _DECIMALS;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function isExcluded(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }
    
    function isCharity(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isCharity[account];
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }
    
    function totalBurn() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tBurnTotal;
    }
    
    function totalCharity() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tCharityTotal;
    }

    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amount must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeAccount(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 'We can not exclude Uniswap router.');
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeAccount(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function setAsCharityAccount(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 'The Uniswap router can not be the charity account.');
        require(!_isCharity[account], "Account is already charity account");
        _isCharity[account] = true;
        _charity.push(account);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");

        // Remove fees for transfers to and from charity account or to excluded account
        bool takeFee = true;
        if (_isCharity[sender] || _isCharity[recipient] || _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            takeFee = false;
        }

        if (!takeFee) removeAllFee();
        
        if (sender != owner() && recipient != owner())
            require(amount <= _MAX_TX_SIZE, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }

        if (!takeFee) restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        uint256 rBurn =  tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);     
        _standardTransferContent(sender, recipient, rAmount, rTransferAmount);
        _sendToCharity(tCharity, sender);
        _reflectFee(rFee, rBurn, rCharity, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function _standardTransferContent(address sender, address recipient, uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount) private {
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        uint256 rBurn =  tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
        _excludedFromTransferContent(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount, rAmount, rTransferAmount);        
        _sendToCharity(tCharity, sender);
        _reflectFee(rFee, rBurn, rCharity, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function _excludedFromTransferContent(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount) private {
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);    
    }
    

    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        uint256 rBurn =  tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
        _excludedToTransferContent(sender, recipient, tAmount, rAmount, rTransferAmount);
        _sendToCharity(tCharity, sender);
        _reflectFee(rFee, rBurn, rCharity, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function _excludedToTransferContent(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount, uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount) private {
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);  
    }

    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        uint256 rBurn =  tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);    
        _bothTransferContent(sender, recipient, tAmount, rAmount, tTransferAmount, rTransferAmount);  
        _sendToCharity(tCharity, sender);
        _reflectFee(rFee, rBurn, rCharity, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }
    
    function _bothTransferContent(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount, uint256 rAmount, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount) private {
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);  
    }

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 rBurn, uint256 rCharity, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee).sub(rBurn).sub(rCharity);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
        _tBurnTotal = _tBurnTotal.add(tBurn);
        _tCharityTotal = _tCharityTotal.add(tCharity);
        _tTotal = _tTotal.sub(tBurn);
    }
    

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) = _getTBasics(tAmount, _TAX_FEE, _BURN_FEE, _CHARITY_FEE);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = getTTransferAmount(tAmount, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRBasics(tAmount, tFee, currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = _getRTransferAmount(rAmount, rFee, tBurn, tCharity, currentRate);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
    }
    
    function _getTBasics(uint256 tAmount, uint256 taxFee, uint256 burnFee, uint256 charityFee) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = ((tAmount.mul(taxFee)).div(_GRANULARITY)).div(100);
        uint256 tBurn = ((tAmount.mul(burnFee)).div(_GRANULARITY)).div(100);
        uint256 tCharity = ((tAmount.mul(charityFee)).div(_GRANULARITY)).div(100);
        return (tFee, tBurn, tCharity);
    }
    
    function getTTransferAmount(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity) private pure returns (uint256) {
        return tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tBurn).sub(tCharity);
    }
    
    function _getRBasics(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        return (rAmount, rFee);
    }
    
    function _getRTransferAmount(uint256 rAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tBurn, uint256 tCharity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 rBurn = tBurn.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rBurn).sub(rCharity);
        return rTransferAmount;
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }

    function _sendToCharity(uint256 tCharity, address sender) private {
        uint256 currentRate = _getRate();
        uint256 rCharity = tCharity.mul(currentRate);
        address currentCharity = _charity[0];
        _rOwned[currentCharity] = _rOwned[currentCharity].add(rCharity);
        _tOwned[currentCharity] = _tOwned[currentCharity].add(tCharity);
        emit Transfer(sender, currentCharity, tCharity);
    }

    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_TAX_FEE == 0 && _BURN_FEE == 0 && _CHARITY_FEE == 0) return;
        
        ORIG_TAX_FEE = _TAX_FEE;
        ORIG_BURN_FEE = _BURN_FEE;
        ORIG_CHARITY_FEE = _CHARITY_FEE;
        
        _TAX_FEE = 0;
        _BURN_FEE = 0;
        _CHARITY_FEE = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _TAX_FEE = ORIG_TAX_FEE;
        _BURN_FEE = ORIG_BURN_FEE;
        _CHARITY_FEE = ORIG_CHARITY_FEE;
    }
    
    function _getTaxFee() private view returns(uint256) {
        return _TAX_FEE;
    }

    function _getMaxTxAmount() private pure returns(uint256) {
        return _MAX_TX_SIZE;
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: The error message is from web3, not from Solidity. Please edit your question and show how you pass data to the constructor.

Comment: Postet the new changed constructor, and still the same problem.
Is it necessary to have this part of a code?

Comment: Please do not post the edit as an answer. It should be an edit to the question. See [FAQ] and [help] for more tips... However, I meant the code that deploys your contract (and passed values to the constructor). Based on the error message, I'm assuming you're using JavaScript `web3js` package and its snippet `new web3.eth.Contract()`, or `truffle` package and `MyContract.new()`... The error is most likely originated from the JS script and data that you pass to the `new Contract` or `MyContract.new()`, this is the snippet I'm asking for.